# Getting an output from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created this stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddNewMaterialType4 
     (@category varchar(15), 
      @materialType varchar(50),
      @userID varchar(15), 
      @result1 varchar(15) OUTPUT)
AS
    DECLARE @count1 INT;
    SET @count1 = 0;

    SELECT @count1 = COUNT(*) 
    FROM [vmsMaterialType]
    WHERE category = @category 
      AND materialType = @materialType;

    IF @count1 = 0
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO [vmsMaterialType] ([category], [materialType],[createdBy])
        VALUES (@category, @materialType, @userID);

        SET @result1 = 'Success';
    END
    ELSE
       SET @result1 = 'Fail';
GO
```

When I execute the following I am not getting the result I expect (Success/Fail) instead its giving me the output what ever I declare result1 as.

```
declare 
    @result1 varchar(15) = '1';
begin 
    execute AddNewMaterialType4 @category = 'Beef', @materialtYPE = '25 Trim', @userID = 'JJ',  @result1 = @result1;
    print @result1;
end;
```

Comment: specify `@result1 = @result1 output` instead of just `@result1 = @result1` when you call the proc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `execute AddNewMaterialType4` call, you have to explicitly state that `@result1` is an `output` variable. Try this instead:

```
declare 
    @result1 varchar(15) = '1';
begin 
    execute AddNewMaterialType4 @category = 'Beef', @materialtYPE = '25 Trim', @userID = 'JJ',  @result1 = @result1 output;
    print @result1;
end;
```

Comment: What is the use initializing the `@result1` variable ?

Comment: There is none. I was simply copy/pasting the original code. I'm pretty sure the OP just set that to distinguish between the "true" or "false" values they expected from something else.

Comment: @xedni is there a difference between 'output' and 'out'? They both seem to work fine.

Comment: I have a couple years of plsql experience... transition is not as straightforward as i thought it would be .. :P